# How to find and provide C++ library headers for clang?

Tags: c++, macos, clang, llvm, std

I've built LLVM and Clang from sources using [following instruction](https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) in order to try some of the latest C++ features.

When I try to compile basic C++ program using this clang I get errors about missing basic headers:

```
% /usr/local/bin/clang++ -std=c++20 main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:1:
main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'array' file not found
#include <array>
```

I similarly have brew installed clang, which works perfectly.

The instruction mentions providing C++ library headers to clang, but I don't understand:

1. How to locate those?
2. How to make sure, that they are also up to date to support latest C++ features?

I have MacOS Monterey 12.4

Comment: You should not need to find those headers manually, your installation is broken, you need to find out why and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify a path to the sdk for your target platform.

You can retreive this by relying on `xcrun`:

```bash
/usr/local/bin/clang++ -isysroot $(xcrun --show-sdk-path) -std=c++20 main.cpp
```

In case you want to target other platforms (in the example bellow, for iphone) you have to specify both the target triple and the path to the appropiate sdk:

```bash
/usr/local/bin/clang++ -target arm64-apple-ios -isysroot $(xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path) -std=c++20 main.cpp
```

There is also an alternative to the `-isysroot` option. You could set up the `SDKROOT` environment variable to point to the target sdk path:

```bash
export SDKPATH=$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)
/usr/local/bin/clang++ -std=c++20 main.cpp
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Is there a way not to type this option every time I compile? The other clang works without it. Is there a variable to set before building from source?

Comment: I haven't found a variable to set at compile time. The alternative that I found is to use the `SDKROOT` environment variable; I edited my answer to show it. You could set this environment variable in an initialization script (or an equivalent of `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` depending on the shell you're using).